# Pulling video from CDN for HTML5 banner ad

Tags: html, video, cdn

I am new to coding. I have a client, big one, that I create HTML5 ads for. They would like me to create an ad using video. I normally use bodymovin to export animations from After Effects.

This time I used Google Ad Designer, I imported the video (.webm) and embedded it using the  tag. The file size compressed is about 1.5mb.

Can I use a CDN provider to host the video and then call up the URL in the HTML code? If I do this, it takes the file size down to 17kb. It's just a container for the player, no actual video file.

These ads are getting millions of impressions a month. So if it's possible to do it this way, the CDN provider needs to be able to handle the traffic.

Comment: I'd imagine the answer depends on the ad network. People chucking 1.5 MB ads at me is part of why I use adblock, though.